# iOS Facebook Integration Like Instagram

Tags: ios, facebook, sharing, account

I have an app setup atm using an email and password login, I'm wondering how I can add a facebook connection between the user's account and facebook just like Instagram. Does it automatically login to facebook everytime? I know you just click facebook when you're uploading a new pic and it posts to fb at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Instagram currently uses the Facebook SDK for iOS but I would recommend using the [Facebook Open Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview/). It's much easier to use and extremely straight forward on calls to get photos, posts, likes, etc.

Here's basically what you need to do:

1.) Import the `Social.Framework` and `Accounts.Framework`

2.) Allocate an `ACAccountStore`

3.) Create an `ACAccountType` of `ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook` from that `ACAccountStore`

4.) Create a iOS Facebook ID key on developer.facebook.com

5.) Create a `NSMutableDictionary` with the initial account permissions and audience types and pass that into `requestAccessToAccountsWithType:` like so:

```
NSArray *permissions = @[@"read_stream"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"123456789",ACFacebookAppIdKey,permissions,ACFacebookPermissionsKey,ACFacebookAudienceFriends,ACFacebookAudienceKey, nil];
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType options:dict completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    //check for permission granted and errors and ask for more permissions or do whatever requests you want
    }
```

6.) Once you have your necessary permissions all you have to do is perform `SLRequest` calls and retrieve the data in the completion handler. Check out the various permission strings and the facebook dev site and you'll be good to go. Hope it helps!

Comment: No problem! Let me know if you have trouble